# Is my sourdough starter ready

Tags: bread, sourdough, sourdough-starter

[image]I’ve been attempting to make sourdough starter for the first time over the last week. I’ve followed the recipe from this website:
https://www.coles.com.au/recipes-inspiration/recipes/sourdough-starter

I’ve used spelt flour which is about 11% protein and bread flour which is also about 11%.

I’ve noted that it smells good (i.e doesn’t smell astringent (I was told to look out for this)) and has a yoghurt like consistency. However, I’ve noticed that it doesn’t rise and doesn’t have the bubbles one would usually expect for sourdough starter (not at the level in the photo from the recipe linked above).

My question is, would it be ready to use?

Appreciate your feedback/suggestions.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have lots of sourdough questions and answers, but my quick search did not locate one that specifically responds to your question. According to [Maurizio (lots of good info in this link)](https://www.theperfectloaf.com/guides/sourdough-starter/), in general, a starter is "ripe" or ready to use when is has risen, you see bubbles on top and around the edges, and it smells sour.  I usually like to time my use of the starter  as close to its peak of rising in its starter container as possible.  It's hard to tell from your picture from above.  There are some helpful pictures on the linked page. It sounds like from your description that you are on the right track.

Comment: My wife is learning all about sourdough currently and it is (sometimes) driving her around the bend. There are lots of websites that help with this (she sometimes uses pantrymamma.com) and have discussions about this particular issue. I don't have specific advice but there is a **lot** of people out there posting and discussing all about sourdough/starter. Worth looking for.